# How to create a query using typeorm query builder to filder data from the database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I am just new to typeorm , I am using nodejs/nestjs , I am trying to create a query where in data from the database which is the course could be filter by instructor which is the firstname and lastname , filter by course_name and filter courses by subject. I tried using 'where' and 'orWhere' but cant seem to wrap things up, Anyone can give an advice of a better implementation ? Thank you. Much appreciated.

The query below is working , I am having trouble with the "where" condition

## Code

```
async findAll(options: IPaginationOptions, query): Promise<Pagination<CourseEntity>> {
    console.log('query :', query);
    const courses = await getRepository(CourseEntity)
      .createQueryBuilder('course')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('course.user', 'user')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('course.subject', 'subject')
      // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/camelcase
      .where('course.course_name = :course_name', { course_name: query.course_name });

    return paginate<CourseEntity>(courses, options);
  }
```

## here is the query param

```
query : { limit: '10', firstname: 'mark', lastname: 'gunn' , course_name: 'Comscie'}
```

## Sample data from the database

```
 {
            "id": 4,
            "course_name": "BS-IT",
            "description": "BS-IT DBMS",
            "created": "2020-03-19T16:40:46.000Z",
            "updated": "2020-03-19T16:40:46.000Z",
            "user": {
                "id": 20,
                "firstname": "Mark",
                "lastname": "Gunn",
                "role": "Instructor",
                "email": "mark@gmail.com",
                "isActive": false,
                "created": "2020-03-19T16:06:21.000Z",
                "updated": "2020-03-19T16:06:34.000Z"
            },
            "subject": {
                "id": 2,
                "subject_name": "IT 100",
                "description": "Fundamandetals",
                "created": "2020-03-18T03:58:34.000Z",
                "updated": "2020-03-18T03:58:34.000Z"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks good. Just add other conditions with andWhere

Answer (score 0):

For my project with Typeorm, I prefer use the Find Option Object (https://typeorm.io/#/find-options), because it's easier to generate request from an object but you can't do some advanced join (but in your case it's totally ok)

They are not better implementation just multiple solutions.